# Favorite fragment using SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm adding a favorite button to my android application that saves pharmacies
in a fragment using SharedPreference and i get this error "Unreachable statement" in the line where i change the color of the button favorite whene it's clicked

```
if (checkFavoriteItem(pharmacie)) {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);  /********error*********/
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("red");
    } else {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("grey");
    }

   return convertView;}
```

this is the full PharmacyArrayAdapter activity:

```
public class PharmacyArrayAdapterfav extends ArrayAdapter<Pharmacie> {
Context myContext;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Pharmacie> pharmacie;

SharedPreference sharedPreference;
private Context context;

public PharmacyArrayAdapterfav(Context context, List<Pharmacie> pharmacie) {
    super(context, R.layout.liste_layout, pharmacie);

    this.context = context;
    this.pharmacie = pharmacie;
    myContext=context;

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}



private class ViewHolder {

    TextView nomTextView;
    TextView villeTextView;
    ImageView img_favorite;
    TextView lonTextView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pharmacie.size();
}

@Override
public Pharmacie getItem(int position) {
    return pharmacie.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nomTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewNom);
        holder.villeTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtViewVille);

        holder.img_favorite = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_favorite);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Pharmacie pharmacie = (Pharmacie) getItem(position);
    holder.nomTextView.setText(pharmacie.getNom());
    holder.villeTextView.setText(pharmacie.getVille());


    return convertView;
if (checkFavoriteItem(pharmacie)) {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("red");
    } else {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("grey");
    }

   return convertView;}



/*Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Pharmacie checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<Pharmacie> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (Pharmacie product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

@Override
public void add(Pharmacie phar) {
    super.add(phar);
    pharmacie.add(phar);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void remove(Pharmacie phar) {
    super.remove(phar);
    pharmacie.remove(phar);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

And also i want to know how to save the list to a specific user that finds his list of favorites after he logs in and clicks favorites button ,please i need help, thank you.

Comment: please include the code for `checkFavoriteItem` method. It appears that it always returns true.

Comment: Unreachable code is not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: this is the methode public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Pharmacie checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<Pharmacie> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (Pharmacie product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

Comment: I've finally figured it out. Check out the answer, it surely will work for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, I totally didn't see a very obvious reason why you have unreachable code - you have an extra `return` that shouldn't be there:

```
Pharmacie pharmacie = (Pharmacie) getItem(position);
holder.nomTextView.setText(pharmacie.getNom());
holder.villeTextView.setText(pharmacie.getVille());


return convertView; //THIS ONE -> just remove it and it'll work
if (checkFavoriteItem(pharmacie)) {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("red");
    } else {
        holder.img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        holder.img_favorite.setTag("grey");
    }

   return convertView;
}
```

Unreachable code warning is usually **this**^, having a return that is not in an if branch and some code after it, it means that the method will always `return` at that point and will **never** run the code below it. It's not an error per se, it's just **IDE** warning you that you might have mistakenly put return where you didn't mean to.